# re.match works via command line but fails when run through a script

Tags: python, regex

So I have a script that parses through a tomcat access log and then matches each line with a regex pattern. Now if I run the regex via command line (invoking python3 interpreter using python3 on a terminal) on a corresponding line from that log I get a match however if I run the script using the same regex I get nada. Not sure why.

Output from command line:

```
>>> obj = re.compile(r'''(?P<bytes_32>[a-z/\?=0-9]+)
...                      (?P<PeerS>x0a5a906a)
...                      (?P<MsTimestamp>Z([a-f0-9]+|[0-9]+))
...                      (?P<RemotePort>AB([0-9]+))
...                      (?P<RemoteIP>A([0-9\.]+){4})
...                      (?P<PeerIP>C([0-9\.]+){4})
...                      (?P<PeerPort>D[0-9]+)
...                      (?P<LocalIP>E([0-9\.]+){4})
...                      (?P<LocalPort>F[0-9]+)
...                      (?P<HostHeader>w[a-z\._0-9\-]+)
...                      (?P<ContentType>K[a-z/]+)
...                      (?P<Method>m[A-Z]+)
...                      ''', re.VERBOSE)
>>> 
>>> string = "0a5a906a57f41c6c00002ee0ffffffff/abcd/api/v1//examples/1348646x0a5a906aZ726AB46151A11.47.166.200C11.47.166.200D46151E11.47.166.200F8443wexamples-api-nobody.corp.myself.comKapplication/jsonmGET"
>>> match = obj.match(string)
>>> print(match)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 195), match='0a5a906a57f41c6c00002ee0ffffffff/screenr/api/v1//>
```

Output via script:

```
line,obj:  0a5a906a57f41c6c00002ee0ffffffff/abcd/api/v1//examples/1348646x0a5a906aZ726AB46151A11.47.166.200C11.47.166.200D46151E11.47.166.200F8443wexamples-api-nobody.corp.myself.comKapplication/jsonmGET
 re.compile('(?P<bytes_32>[a-z/\\?=0-9]+)\n                     (?P<PeerS>x0a5a906a)\n                     (?P<MsTimestamp>Z([a-f0-9]+|[0-9]+))\n                     (?P<RemotePort>AB([0-9]+))\n                  , re.VERBOSE)
match is: None
```

Why is there a difference in the interpreter and the script when I am using the same input and pattern for both?

Comment: Are you sure there is not whitespace at the start? Try the same regex with `re.search`

Comment: You didn't show the script.  When I pasted your interactive session (which you did show) into a script, and removed the ">>>" and "...." stuff, it worked fine.

Comment: Although the match spanned `span=(0, 192)`. not the 195 endpoint your output showed.  `len(string)` is in fact 192 in what you posted, so something is wrong in what you posted.

Comment: No actually the issue was not with the code or the interpreter as it turns out the log was adding some additional ^A and ^E type of characters. And even though they did not seem to show up in the print output they were embedded in the log file so when I remove them from one of the lines my regex worked just fine.

Comment: obj = re.compile(r'(?P<bytes_32>[a-z/\?=0-9]+)'
                     r'(?P<PeerS>x0a5a906a)'
                     r'(?P<MsTimestamp>Z[a-f0-9]+)'
                     r'(?P<RemotePort>AB[0-9]+)'
                     r'(?P<RemoteIP>A[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)'
                     r'(?P<PeerIP>C[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)'
                     r'(?P<PeerPort>D[0-9]+)'
                     r'(?P<LocalIP>E[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)'

Comment: r'(?P<LocalPort>F[0-9]+)'
                     r'(?P<HostHeader>w[a-z\._0-9\-]+)'
                     r'(?P<ContentType>K[a-z/]+)'
                     r'(?P<Method>m[A-Z]+)'
                )
Doing it this way avoids picking up additional characters which the original regex was doing in some cases.